# bootstrap table-hover is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3.3.4 and I have a problem.
If I check the bootstrap.css file which I am loading, there is a table-hover class, but I can't use it, it just doesn't work, as I can see, table-bordered for example works. I have checked that the bootstrap.js is also loaded. Did anyone else have the same problem? I tried to search it for so long.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please explain the functionality which you are trying to achieve. Have you checked bootstrap documentations weather such a behaviour exist. Also please update your post with some code you have tried.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? According to the documentation, you need to add the `table-hover` class to the table element, and also make sure you've got `<tbody>` too because it targets rows inside the tbody element.

Answer (score 19):

From the [docs on table hover](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-hover-rows), make sure to add the `.table-hover` class to your table element.

Also, as Daniel pointed out, bootstrap looks for a tbody to group your rows because it doesn't want to apply hover styling on the header area.

Also, for some screens, the default hover color can appear very dim so you can try making it darker with the following code:

```css
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover {
  background-color: #D2D2D2;
}
```

#### Here's a working demo in Stack Snippets

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use th instead of td for your tbody columns. That's how I got it working. Using boostrap 4.1.

Comment: please use the edit button under your answer and add an example to show how it should be done. it will help future readers to understand your answer better and find it useful.